# How can I pass arguments to the function pointer in following code?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I tried those code but there is some issue with scope of parameters a and  b. please someone help me out here.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y) {
    return (x + y);
}
void passptr(int( * fp)(int a, int b)) {
    int result = ( * fp)(a, b);
    printf("%d", result);
}
int main() {
    add(3, 5);
    passptr( & add);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no `a` and `b` parameters being passed.  You're passing a single function pointer.

Comment: Compiler warnings are there for good reasons!

Comment: You're confusing the concepts of "naming a function" and "calling a function".

Comment: And that is pure C. Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: The names in the type of the parameter are for human readers only and are ignored by the compiler – your prototype is equivalent to `void passptr(int (*fp)(int, int))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of call is easier to understand if you `typedef` your function pointer:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

// addFuncPtr_t is a pointer to a function that:
// - returns int
// - takes two int arguments
typedef int ( *addFuncPtr_t )( int, int );

int add(int x, int y) {
    return (x + y);
}
void passptr(addFuncPtr_t fp, int a, int b) {
    int result = fp(a, b);
    printf("%d", result);
}
int main() {
    add(3, 5);

    // note that the function is passed separately from
    // the arguments - add(3,5) would *call* the function
    // instead of passing the address of the function
    passptr( add, 3, 5 );
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much typing is saved by the typedef? Also, what does the first line in `main()` `add(3, 5);` do?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's not about saving typing, it's for aiding understanding, as it's obvious that the parameters of the function pointer are unconnected to that of `passptr` when the type is made opaque.

Comment: Yes, the typedef will eliminate the requirement that you use the entire formal function pointer declaration as a parameter when declaring a using function and that does in some way make it easier to understand, but wow, that's a whopper `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *what does the first line in main() add(3, 5); do?*  I just copied the question's original code but added the `typedef`.  You'll have to ask the OP why that's there.  Using a `typedef` doesn't save keystrokes here because it's only used once, but it will help if the type is used often, especially for more complex types.  And `typedef` will greatly aid the readability of code that does things such as return pointers to complex functions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *We all need to make sure we are giving correct answers and not copy/pasting meaningless code as part of the answer. (notice no downvote)*  What is *meaningless* about the call to `add()`?  It *demonstrates* how `add()` works.  It may be trivial in this case, but in the context of a question about passing function pointers, that call has the very meaningful purpose of showing the functionality *sans* function pointer use..  What could possibly be *wrong* with doing that?  Even implying that it's not correct seems to utterly miss its point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :D Just some curiousness though,why we are not passing the address of the function as parameter to passptr(*addFuncPtr_t,int,int), when the formal parameter is actually a pointer? Even though code work for both cases : passptr(add,3,5) and passptr(&add,3,5). Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Endra The `typedef` is defined as a pointer. The code works for both `passptr(add,3,5)` and `passptr(&add,3,5)` for the same reason you can pass an array by just using the unadorned name of the array:  the unadorned name is passed as the address.  Per 6.3.2.1 of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): *a function designator with type ‘‘function returning `type`’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning `type`’’.* Arrays are covered by the preceding paragraph.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Got it. thanx. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void passptr(int (*fp)(int a,int b))
{
    int result=(*fp)(a,b);
    printf("%d",result);
}
```

`a` and `b` here are just descriptive names you have given to the parameters of the function pointer, they aren't declared variables. Just call the function with valid arguments:

```
//call with literals
int result = (*fp)(1,2);

//or variables
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int result = (*fp)(a,b);

//or pass as arguments
void passptr(int (*fp)(int,int), int a, int b) {
    int result = (*fp)(a,b)
}

//and call like this
passptr(&add, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
void passptr(int (*fp)(int, int), int a, int b)  // corrected argument list
{
 int result=(*fp)(a,b);
 printf("%d",result);
}
int  main()
{
 add(3,5);              // this is useless leftover from your original code
 passptr(&add, 3, 5);   // added parameters 3 and 5 here
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

In your `void passptr(int( * fp)(int a, int b))` `a` and `b` are not parameters to the `passptr` function but just placeholders.

Comment: Just a hint, what does `add(3,5);` do in your code above?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it's probably leftover test code from the OP. Is has actually no purpose.

Comment: I was fairly certain that was the case, I just wanted to make certain you were aware it was there and that it probably didn't look the best to have meaningless code in an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y) {
    return (x + y);
}
void passptr(int( * fp)(int a, int b)) {
    int result = ( * fp)(3, 5);
    printf("%d", result);
}
int main() {
    add(3, 5);
    passptr( & add);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you use `a` and `b` for in `passptr()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, it's much simpler with templates :

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y) {
    return (x + y);
}

template<typename funcPtr>
void passptr(funcPtr f,int a, int b) {
    int result = f(a, b);
    printf("%d", result);
}
int main() {
    passptr(add,3,5);
    return 0;
}
```